# I want to support UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight and UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft only

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, interface-builder

how do I make sure that UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitRight and UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitLeft are not supported.

Basically I want my application to be used ONLY in UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight and UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft

I edited the Info.plist file

```
<string>MainWindow</string>
 <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
 <array>          
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
 </array>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that in every `UIViewController`/`UITabBarController` etc., in the `shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation`, the return says `return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))`;.