# iphone xcode Landscape mode by default

Tags: iphone

how can I set an iphone app to start in Landscape mode? and stays that way

Comment: see also:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647607

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the "Initial interface orientation" app.plist entry to "Landscape" (left or right home button) and add (or more likely, uncomment and edit) the following view controller method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Comment: did you mean:  return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;

Comment: No, I intended it to force a single landscape orientation (that's how I would design it), but your point is quite valid. I guess it comes down to the OP's underlying intent.

Comment: As others have mentioned, `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscape` is not a valid enum; you need `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft` or `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight` if you only wanted one (for reasons passing understanding), or `return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);` to support either landscape orientation.

Comment: Thanks @AdamLuptak. I can't believe I didn't realise this the first time around.

Answer (score 6):

Marcelo's answer is not correct, because `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscape` is not a valid identifier and thus brings up a build fail.

progrmr's answer is correct:

```
return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
```

(Apologies for not commenting on the first answer, but I didn't have enough reputation points when I wrote this...)