# My XCode 4.2 app appears rotated

Tags: interface-builder, xcode4.2

What have I done wrong here?

When I run my app in the IOS emulator it appears like a portrait app being viewed landscape and I have to rotate the IOs emulated iPad to portrait to view my app the right way up.

I have my interface-builder screen set to landscape and want to build a landscape view but it appears that I am actually building a portrait view albeit it in a landscape interface-builder.

How can I change what I am building so that I am building a landscape view that lines up with a landscape iPad screen in the iOs emulator?

I appreciate that the language here is confusing.

Comment: Have you set an initial interface orientation in your info.plist?

Comment: It's been a while since I used 4.2 but doesn't that file appear in the navigator pane for your app in XCode? It might begin with your app name but it will end with info.plist
see here too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761495/iphone-xcode-landscape-mode-by-default