# How do I get my iPhone app to start in Landscape mode?

Tags: iphone, ios, landscape, uiinterfaceorientation, portrait

My app is fixed to landscape mode, yet during viewDidLoad() and even viewWillAppear(), the following portrait dimensions still return:

```
self.view.bounds.size.width = 320.00
self.view.bounds.size.height = 480.00
```

It's not until viewDidAppear() that the actual landscape dimensions result.

```
self.view.bounds.size.width = 480.00
self.view.bounds.size.height = 320.00
```

I find this weird.
Why does this happen!?  and how can I fix this?

Comment: Are you returning YES in your root UIViewController's - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation method?

Comment: I use:  return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);.  Every configuration I could find I set it to landscape.  And still no change.  I'm suspecting it's a "feature" bug in iOS.

Comment: I just went back and read the Apple docs.  viewWillAppear: is called "before any animations are configured for showing the view".  Since rotation is (can be) animated, that's probably why you are seeing the un-rotated sizes.  So I suspect you are right - it is a "feature"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your app's info.plist file, specify the key:

```
 UISupportedInterfaceOrientations
```

with values for landscape left and right:

[image]

**EDIT**:

The raw plist code should look like this:

```
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
```

**Edit 2**

You also need this key which determines the initial orientation of the status bar:

```
 <key>UIInterfaceOrientation</key>
 <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
```

Further, you need to make sure that **ALL** of your view controllers (tabbar, navbar, regular view-controllers) implement

```
 shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation
```

and return a Landscape  (left or right) value.

Here is an Apple docs article on the subject:

[Technical Note TN2244](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2244/_index.html)

And finally, here are some other SO posts on this topic:
[post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761495/iphone-xcode-landscape-mode-by-default) and [post 2.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647607/i-want-to-support-uiinterfaceorientationlandscaperight-and-uiinterfaceorientatio)

Comment: Already have that set. <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
</plist>

Comment: Yes, I get it.  And I'm saying it makes no difference.  Does your code work as it's supposed to?

Comment: @SebastianDwornik please see second edit.  Hopefully this is the whole story now.

Comment: 'Initial interface orientation' (aka. UIInterfaceOrientation) key within the plist file I think finally did it.  Thank you.